# breezejs: Nonscalar navigation properties are readonly

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, breeze

I have the following metadata:

```
var entityTypeParent = {
    shortName: 'ParentItemType',
    namespace: 'MyNamespace',
    autoGeneratedKeyType: Identity,
    defaultResourceName: 'ParentItemTypes',

    dataProperties: {
        id: { dataType: DT.Int32, isPartOfKey: true }
    },

    navigationProperties: {
        users: {
            entityTypeName: 'User',
            isScalar: false,
            associationName: 'ParentItem_User'
        }
    }
};

var entityTypeUser = {
    shortName: 'User',
    namespace: 'MyNamespace',
    autoGeneratedKeyType: Identity,
    defaultResourceName: 'Users',

    dataProperties: {
        loginName: { dataType: DT.String, isPartOfKey: true },
        displayText: {},
        parentItemId: {
            dataType: DT.Int32
        }
    },

    navigationProperties: {
        agendaTask: {
            entityTypeName: 'ParentItemType',
            associationName: 'ParentItem_User',
            foreignKeyNames: ['parentItemId']
        }
    }
};
```

In the UI I have a control (Kendo Multi-Select), which is bound to the ParentItemType.users property (AngularJS binding), which allows to select a user from a list (retrieved using breeze-kendo bridge and 'webApiOData' adapter).

Selecting a user results in an "Error: Nonscalar navigation properties are readonly - entities can be added or removed but the collection may not be changed." exception in setNpValue (https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/blob/397b2a02aa2173175c304eb1b37332f1656db6f5/src/a35_defaultPropertyInterceptor.js#L287).

If I change the definition to isScalar eq true. I get an exception at https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/blob/397b2a02aa2173175c304eb1b37332f1656db6f5/src/a35_defaultPropertyInterceptor.js#L298

context.newValue is an array of user entities.

Is this an error somewhere in my metadata definition? Actually I just want to have multiple users in my ParentItem.

Breeze Version: 1.5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not an error in your metadata definition. This is by design. Nonscalar navigation properties are managed by Breeze. Multi-select controls try to take ownership of the value array and replace it with a new array. Breeze won't allow that because it would be catastrophic and break your entities.

Multi-select controls are a bit of a pain. You need to leverage the events that the control triggers to update the navigation property when the user makes a selection and manually create the association entities from the selected values and delete them if the user unselects them. I don't have an example for KendoUI, but FWIW, here is an Angular2 example for the DevExpress TagBox and the following entity model.

Model(Subject) 1<--->n SubjectVehicleAssociation n<--->1 LookupItem(Vehicle)

There's a bit of work involved. The multi-select controls out of the box only work with basic arrays.

```
<dx-tag-box [dataSource]="adapter.dataSource"
        displayExpr="description"
        [value]="adapter.value"
        [searchEnabled]="true"
        (onSelectionChanged)="adapter.selectionChanged($event)">

</dx-tag-box>
```

Adapter instance creation in the component:

```
let valueConverter: ITagBoxValueConverter<SubjectVehicleAssociation, { code: string, longValue: string }> = {
    match: (item: SubjectVehicleAssociation, lookupItem: { code: string, longValue: string }) => item.abbreviation === lookupItem.code,
    seed: (item: SubjectVehicleAssociation, lookupItem: { code: string, longValue: string }) => {
        item.description = lookupItem.longValue;
        item.abbreviation = lookupItem.code;
        return item;
    }
};
this.adapter = new TagBoxAdapter(SubjectVehicleAssociation,
    () => Promise.resolve(this.vehicleAssociationsLookup),
    this.modelSubjectVehicleRelation,
    'associations',
    valueConverter);
```

And the Adapter implementation:

```
import DataSource from 'devextreme/data/data_source';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

import { Entity, EntityState } from 'breeze-client';

export interface ITagBoxValueConverter<T extends Entity, W> {

    match(value1: T, value2: W): boolean;

    seed(target: T, source: W): T;
}

export class TagBoxAdapter<T extends Entity, W> {

    dataSource: DataSource;

    constructor(private itemType: { new (): T },
        private data: (searchValue?: string, maxSearchResults?: number) => Promise<W[]>,
        private model: any,
        private valueExpr: string,
        private valueConverter: ITagBoxValueConverter<T, W>,
        private maxSearchResults: number = 20) {

        this.initializeDataSource();
    }

    get value(): T[] {
        return _.get<T[]>(this.model, this.valueExpr, []);
    }

    selectionChanged(e: { addedItems: T[], removedItems: T[] }) {

        e.addedItems.forEach(item => {
            if (item.entityAspect && item.entityAspect.entityState.isDeleted()) {
                // Real entity, needs to be resurrected
                item.entityAspect.rejectChanges();
            } else {
                // Placeholder entity, needs to be attached first
                this.model.entityAspect.entityManager.attachEntity(item, EntityState.Added);
                this.value.push(item);
            }
        })

        e.removedItems.forEach(item => {
            item.entityAspect.setDeleted();
        })

    };

    private initializeDataSource() {
        let sourceData = (searchValue: string, maxSearchResults: number) => {
            return this.data(searchValue, maxSearchResults).then((results) => {
                return results.map(dataItem => {
                    // Find existing association entity if exists
                    let item = _.find(this.value, item => this.valueConverter.match(item, dataItem));
                    if (item) return item;

                    // Not associated yet, return placeholder association entity
                    return this.valueConverter.seed(new this.itemType(), dataItem);
                })
            });
        };

        this.dataSource = new DataSource({
            // The LoadOptions interface is defined wrong it's lacking the search properties
            load: (loadOptions: any) => {
                let searchValue = loadOptions.searchValue ? loadOptions.searchValue : "";
                return sourceData(searchValue, this.maxSearchResults).then(data => data.filter(item => !_.intersection(this.value, [item]).length));
            },
            byKey: (key) => {
                return sourceData(key, 1).then((data) => _.find(data, key));
            }
        });
    }
}
```